# Is there a way to hide images from the media library?

Tags: 7, files, media

I'm using the media module, and I'd like to hide some images (in a certain subdirectory) from the files overview in the admin area.

Is this possible?

Thx in advance!

Comment: I believe this requires rolling your own browser. Media supports Views, so create a View that behaves as you want, and add it to Media.

Comment: @Letharion It looks like building a view and using bulk operations is indeed an option, but then I have to rebuild from scratch. Is there a way I can import the current view into views and the just adjust some details? 
Like the admin_views module does for nodes. 
thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in version 2.x of the media module the media browser is implemented as a view. This is the key to doing any sort of customisation to the browser. You should be able to see it in admin/structure/views and override it as you would with any other view.

The media browser view uses files as it's base type. It has some existing filters for filename, type etc. You can add another one that filters by path. If you use the *starts with* operator and value *public://foo/*. That will end up doing a SQL LIKE query on the *uri* column of the file_managed table, which should give you what you want.

It's worth noting that you can customise the media browser only for certain file fields. To do that, clone the view instead of overriding it, thereby giving you two media browsers. Then for each field that uses a media widget, you need to choose which browser(s) you want.

Comment: thx @Erik, I'm well aware of that. My question concerns the media library in the main content administration area (admin/content/file). There isn't a view available for that, so I'd have to rebuild all that.

Comment: @jeroen sorry I misread the original question. Looks like the query you want to change is in file_entity_admin_files(). As a workaround you might be able to alter that form somehow, otherwise I think you're right in that you'd have to replace this page with your own view.